# Validate Exchange oAuth token

Tags: oauth, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

I am trying to validate an oAuth token that my server-side code is receiving.

The server-side code is using the Exchange Managed API and the token that is being sent was retrieved by my add-in from Exchange using the `Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(callback)` method in the Outlook API.

I am running into an issue when I call the `token.Validate(uri)` method:

```
var token = (AppIdentityToken)AuthToken.Parse(rawToken);
token.Validate(new Uri(hostUri));
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/use-the-token-validation-library):

> *hostUri*: The fully qualified URI to the page in your Outlook add-in that called **getUserIdentityTokenAsync**.

To get the hostUri from within the page in the add-in, I use:

```
var hostUri = location.href.split('?')[0];
```

However, using that provided URI, causes an error when trying to validate the token:

[image: Error message]

I am confused as to why it would be using the URI of where the add-in is located instead of using the public key of the Identity Provider that issued the token (i.e. Exchange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EWS token validation library do will validate the signature of the token via the public key.

The host Uri is used to validate the **aud** claim in the id_token to validate that this token is passed from your application instead of other application.

Please ensure that the **Uri** is match the host page, you can parse the the id_token through [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to see the real **Uri**(aud) in the token.

Comment: Yes, turns out that the token validation library looks in the `amurl` field to know where it can get the public key to validate the token. In our case, we set up exchange in a test VM with a made up domain name, so we were not able to reach it, once that was fixed (add record to host file) it was able to get the public key and validate token.